# How to implement horizontally infinite scrolling UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to implement `UICollectionView` that scrolls horizontally and infinitely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing cells in demands in UICollectionView with vertical infinite scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246394/showing-cells-in-demands-in-uicollectionview-with-vertical-infinite-scroll)

Comment: Achieved this with scrollView - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275472/4776634

Comment: This thread has some useful information in it. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/11333

Answer (score 53):

If your data is static and you want a kind of circular behavior, you can do something like this:

```
var dataSource = ["item 0", "item 1", "item 2"]

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Int.max // instead of returnin dataSource.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let itemToShow = dataSource[indexPath.row % dataSource.count]
    let cell = UICollectionViewCell() // setup cell with your item and return
    return cell
}
```

Basically you say to your collection view that you have a huge number of cells (Int.max won't be infinite, but might do the trick), and you access your data source using the % operator. In my example we'll end up with "item 0", "item 1", "item 2", "item 0", "item 1", "item 2" ....

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Very elegant solution! Just an addition - if you want to make the collection scrollable to the left from the beginning, you can use: CollectionView.scrollToItem() and give it some big value just after its initialization.

Comment: @Gocy015 even if you tell it there are millions of items, if you use reusable cells, it will only ever create just enough to fill the view and have some prepared off screen.

Comment: returning `Int.max` crashes the Simulator :(

Comment: @tarrball ,  yes , but cell reuse mechanism will only solve memory problems , if the size of your cell depends on the data it's displaying , and you calculate their size/height inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` or `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` , these method will be called as many times as your `numberOf .. InSection` returned. I'm guessing this will probably cause a performance issue ?  There will still be millions of unnecessary calls here even if i do some caching.

Comment: @Gocy015 even if the size is calculated for each cell, assuming every cell size is dynamic, it will still only run the calculation for the few cells currently being displayed or about to be displayed. It does this stuff very well, so I'm not convinced there would be a performance hit. I've nested `UITableViews` in `UICollectionViewCells` using this method and everything runs very smooth.

Comment: @tarrball , no !  since `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` , the system will calculate the size for each cell when initializing the scroll view to determine its `contentSize` , i haven't test this approach on a real-world app ,just concerned that i might raise a performance issue , it's also good to know that you've implement this and it's working fine.

Comment: And what happesn if user swipe left from start? Will it go towards -1?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it @Saad but `indexPath.row` will never be negative. If you somehow have negative indexes, when `index % dataSource.count` result is negative you have to add `dataSource.count` to keep accessing the data source in the same order

Comment: Use Int (INT_MAX) rather Int.max, it will not crash rest is fine

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938580/making-a-uicollectionview-continuously-scroll

Comment: Its crashing for Int(INT_MAX) and Int.max for both Simulator and Device.

Comment: its crashing for Int(INT_MAX)

Comment: not a good solution, crashes when my CI runs tests on simulators

Comment: This is obviously not going to work by creating 2 billion items... first it'll crash due to out of memory, second it's not infinite scrolling where the collection view resets after the reaching the end.

Comment: This is a good solution but it needs two critical adjustments to work with modern API: Int.max does indeed crash the simulator, but do we need the number to actually be that high? A number like 1000000 doesn't crash the simulator, and works just as well. Also, one needs to disable any kind of automatic cell sizing and just use fixed cell sizes to avoid heavy strain on CPU and memory.

Answer (score 17):

Apparently the closest to good solution was proposed by the **Manikanta Adimulam**. The cleanest solution would be to add the last element at the beginning of the data list, and the first one to the last data list position (ex: [4] [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [0]), so we scroll to the first array item when we are triggering the last list item and vice versa. This will work for collection views with one visible item:

1. Subclass UICollectionView.
2. Override UICollectionViewDelegate and override the following methods:

   ```
   public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       let numberOfCells = items.count
       let page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(cellWidth)
       if page == 0 { // we are within the fake last, so delegate real last
           currentPage = numberOfCells - 1
       } else if page == numberOfCells - 1 { // we are within the fake first, so delegate the real first
           currentPage = 0
       } else { // real page is always fake minus one
          currentPage = page - 1
       }
       // if you need to know changed position, you can delegate it
       customDelegate?.pageChanged(currentPage)
   }


   public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       let numberOfCells = items.count
       if numberOfCells == 1 {
           return
       }
       let regularContentOffset = cellWidth * CGFloat(numberOfCells - 2)
       if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= cellWidth * CGFloat(numberOfCells - 1)) {
           scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x - regularContentOffset, y: 0.0)
       } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < cellWidth) {
           scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x + regularContentOffset, y: 0.0)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Override layoutSubviews() method inside your UICollectionView in order to always to make a correct offset for the first item:

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()

       let numberOfCells = items.count
       if numberOfCells > 1 {
           if contentOffset.x == 0.0 {
               contentOffset = CGPoint(x: cellWidth, y: 0.0)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Override init method and calculate your cell dimensions:

   ```
   let layout = self.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
   cellPadding = layout.minimumInteritemSpacing
   cellWidth = layout.itemSize.width
   ```

Works like a charm!
If you want to achieve this effect with collection view having multiple visible items, then use solution posted [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180205005000/masonlamy.com/infinite-scrolling-uicollectionview-using-swift/).

Comment: I used a very similar solution. This works well for collectionViews that use paging and show one cell at a time. I am also using the collectionView(sizeForItemAt indexPath) function to size the cells based on the device width, and the accepted answer will crash the app because it sets the size for every single cell... so making a ridiculously large collection won't work in my case.

Answer (score 6):

I have implemented infinite scrolling in `UICollectionView`. Made the code available in github. You can give it a try. Its in swift 3.0.

[InfiniteScrolling](https://github.com/Vishal-Singh-Panwar/InfiniteScrolling/)

You can add it using pod. Usage is pretty simple. Just intialise the `InfiniteScrollingBehaviour` as below.

```
infiniteScrollingBehaviour = InfiniteScrollingBehaviour(withCollectionView: collectionView, andData: Card.dummyCards, delegate: self)
```

and implement required delegate method to return a configured `UICollectionViewCell`. An example implementation will look like:

```
func configuredCell(forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, originalIndex: Int, andData data: InfiniteScollingData, forInfiniteScrollingBehaviour behaviour: InfiniteScrollingBehaviour) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath)
        if let collectionCell = cell as? CollectionViewCell,
            let card = data as? Card {
            collectionCell.titleLabel.text = card.name
        }
        return cell
    }
```

It will add appropriate leading and trailing boundary elements in your original data set and will adjust collectionView's `contentOffset`.

In the callback methods, it will give you index of an item in the original data set.

Answer (score 5):

***Tested code***

I achieved this by simply *repeating* cell for x amount of times. As following,

Declare how many loops would you like to have

```
let x = 50
```

Implement `numberOfItems`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count*x // large scrolling: lets see who can reach the end :p
}
```

Add this utility function to calculate `arrayIndex` given an indexPath row

```
func arrayIndexForRow(_ row : Int)-> Int {
    return row % myArray.count
}
```

Implement `cellForItem`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
    let arrayIndex = arrayIndexForRow(indexPath.row)
    let modelObject = myArray[arrayIndex]
    // configure cell
    return cell
}
```

Add utility function to scroll to middle of `collectionView` at given index

```
func scrollToMiddle(atIndex: Int, animated: Bool = true) {
    let middleIndex = atIndex + x*yourArray.count/2
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: middleIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: It is very nice solution. Thanks for the help. It would be more beneficial if you could help in scrolling automatically i.e. after x second collection view should scroll to next position. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Also implying that your data is static and that all your `UICollectionView` cells should have the same size, I found [this promising solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20180205005000/masonlamy.com/infinite-scrolling-uicollectionview-using-swift/).

You could download the example project over at [github](https://github.com/masoapps/infinite-uicollectionview) and run the project yourself. The code in the ViewController that creates the `UICollectionView` is pretty straight forward.

**You basically follow these steps:**

- Create a `InfiniteCollectionView` in Storyboard
- Set `infiniteDataSource` and `infiniteDelegate`
- Implement the necessary functions that create your infinitely scrolling cells

Comment: this link you added not working anymore please update or remove it

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh, Fixed the broken link.

Comment: Created a project based on InfiniteCollectionView  here: https://github.com/vineet15889/Restaurant-menu

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for infinitely and horizontally scrolling collection views whose data sources are appended to at the end--append to your data source in `scrollViewDidScroll` and call `reloadData()` on your collection view. It will maintain the scroll offset.

Sample code below. I use my collection view for a paginated date picker, where I load more pages (of entire months) when the user is towards the right end (second to the last):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentPage = self.customView.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.customView.collectionView.bounds.size.width

    if currentPage > CGFloat(self.months.count - 2) {
        let nextMonths = self.generateMonthsFromDate(self.months[self.months.count - 1], forPageDirection: .Next)
        self.months.appendContentsOf(nextMonths)
        self.customView.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

// DOESN'T WORK - adding more months to the left
//    if currentPage < 2 {
//        let previousMonths = self.generateMonthsFromDate(self.months[0], forPageDirection: .Previous)
//        self.months.insertContentsOf(previousMonths, at: 0)
//        self.customView.collectionView.reloadData()
//    }
}
```

**EDIT**: - This doesn't seem to work when you are inserting at the beginning of the data source.

Answer (score 0):

in case the `cell.width == collectionView.width`, this solution has worked for me:

first, you need your `items * 2`:

```
func set(items colors: [UIColor]) {
    items = colors + colors
}
```

Then add these two computed variables to determine the indices:

```
var firstCellIndex: Int {
        var targetItem = items.count / 2 + 1
        
        if !isFirstCellSeen {
            targetItem -= 1
            isFirstCellSeen = true
        }
        
        return targetItem
    }
    
    var lastCellIndex: Int {
        items.count / 2 - 2
    }
```

as you can see, the `firstCellIndex` has a flag `isFirstCellSeen`. this flag is needed when the CV appears for the first time, otherwise, it will display `items[1]` instead of `items[0]`. So do not forget to add that flag into your code.

The main logic happens here:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        scroll(to: firstCellIndex)
    } else if indexPath.item == items.count - 1 {
        scroll(to: lastCellIndex)
    }
}

private func scroll(to row: Int) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(
            at: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0),
            at: .centeredHorizontally,
            animated: false
        )
    }
}
```

That was it. The collection view scroll should now be infinite. I liked this solution because it does not require any additional pods and is very easy to understand: you just multiply your cv items by 2 and then always scroll to the middle when the `indexPath == 0` or `indexPath == lastItem`

Answer (score -2):

1. To apply this infinite loop functionality You should have proper collectionView layout
2. You need to add the first element of the array at last and last element of the array at first
   ex:- array = [1,2,3,4]
   presenting array = [4,1,2,3,4,1]

   ```
   func infinateLoop(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       var index = Int((scrollView.contentOffset.x)/(scrollView.frame.width))
       guard currentIndex != index else {
           return
       }
       currentIndex = index
       if index <= 0 {
           index = images.count - 1
           scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: (scrollView.frame.width+60) * CGFloat(images.count), y: 0), animated: false)
       } else if index >= images.count + 1 {
           index = 0
           scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: (scrollView.frame.width), y: 0), animated: false)
       } else {
           index -= 1
       }
       pageController.currentPage = index
   }

   func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
       infinateLoop(scrollView: scrollView)
   }
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       infinateLoop(scrollView: scrollView)
   }
   ```

Comment: use it in collectionview delegate
for collection view layout refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585822/how-to-center-align-the-cells-of-a-uicollectionview-in-swift3-0

Answer (score -3):

The answers provided here are good to implement the feature. But in my opinion they contain some low level updates (setting content offset, manipulating the data source ...) which can be avoided. If you're still not satisfied and looking for a different approach here's what I've done.

The main idea is to update the number of cells whenever you reach the cell before the last one. Each time you increase the number of items by 1 so it gives the illusion of infinite scrolling. To do that we can utilize `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` function to detect when the user has finished scrolling, and then update the number of items in the collection view. Here's a code snippet to achieve that:

```swift
class InfiniteCarouselView: UICollectionView {

    var data: [Any] = []

    private var currentIndex: Int?
    private var currentMaxItemsCount: Int = 0
    // Set up data source and delegate
}

extension InfiniteCarouselView: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Set the current maximum to a number above the maximum count by 1
        currentMaxItemsCount = max(((currentIndex ?? 0) + 1), data.count) + 1
        return currentMaxItemsCount

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row % data.count
        let item = data[row]
        // Setup cell
        return cell
    }
}

extension InfiniteCarouselView: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }

    // Detect when the collection view has finished scrolling to increase the number of items in the collection view
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Get the current index. Note that the current index calculation will keep changing because the collection view is expanding its content size based on the number of items (currentMaxItemsCount)
        currentIndex = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.contentSize.width * CGFloat(currentMaxItemsCount))
        // Reload the collection view to get the new number of items
        reloadData()
    }
}
```

### Pros

- Straightforward implementation
- No use of Int.max (Which in my own opinion is not a good idea)
- No use of an arbitrary number (Like 50 or something else)
- No change or manipulation of the data
- No manual update of the content offset or any other scroll view attributes

### Cons

- Paging should be enabled (Although the logic can be updated to support no paging)
- Need to maintain a reference for some attributes (current index, current maximum count)
- Need to reload the collection view on each scroll end (Not a big deal if the visible cells are minimal). This might affect you drastically if you're loading something asynchronously without caching (Which is a bad practice and data should be cached outside the cells)
- Doesn't work if you want infinite scroll in both directions