# Making a UICollectionView continuously scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a game where I need to have a board of letters continuously scrolling, and looping through a set of data (`A, D, X, S, R, P, F, G, H, Y, W, M`) (Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3rO8TbkS-U&feature=youtu.be). When a user taps on a letter, the letter needs to be removed from the board. I can't have the board stop scrolling, it needs to continuously scroll.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I've been trying to do this with a UICollectionView, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 25):

Infinite scrolling in collection view can be achieved with a very easy technique.

**Note: This technique is reportedly not working from iOS 12. For better results I am adding a new method after explaining this one.**

1) Return a huge number in numberOfItemsInSection delegate method of collection view.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

     return Int(INT_MAX)
}
```

2) Modulo the number of items in collection view with the count of your array or dictionary whatever you are using to get repeating data.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
                cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
     let displayText = indexPath.row % 10
     cell.displayLabel.text = String(displayText)
     return cell

}
```

Here i have no data thus i am using indexPath.row to display the row number in my label.

Suppose i have 10 data to display and currently i have huge number of items so i modulo 10 with number the current item. you can modulo the row with count of your array or dictionary as below:

```
let displayText = aryData.count % 10
```

**Now explaining another technique which will work in any iOS and will give better output:**

1) multiply the number of items in array by 2 and then we need to play with the content offset of collectionview. I am posting the code below on how to handle this technique.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return aryData.count * 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = colView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! colViewCell

        var index = indexPath.item
        if index > aryData.count - 1 {
            index -= aryData.count
        }
        cell.displayLabel.text = aryData[index % aryData.count]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // if collection view scrolls vertically, use offset.y else comment below code
        var offset = collectionView.contentOffset
        let height = collectionView.contentSize.height
        if offset.y < height/4 {
            offset.y += height/2
            collectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
        } else if offset.y > height/4 * 3 {
            offset.y -= height/2
            collectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
        }

        // if collection view scrolls horizontally, use offset.x else comment below line of code
        // In my case the collectionview scrolls vertically this I am commenting below line of code
        //        let width = collectionView.contentSize.width
        //        if offset.x < width/4 {
        //            offset.x += width/2
        //            collectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
        //        } else if offset.x > width/4 * 3 {
        //            offset.x -= width/2
        //            collectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
        //        }
    }
```

Below is the output of this code.

[image: Infinite Scrolling Collection View]

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas on how to make the collectionView automatically scroll without the user swiping?

Comment: If you want to perform swipe action without letting the user swipe then i guess you should create a timer using NSTimer and call the method which you call on users swipe. If you have doubt using NSTimer let me know. I may be wrong but this may work :)

Comment: The link no longer works. this is why you should always paste the solution, in your answer - rather than just the link.

Comment: @Tander I have updated my answer with a solution. Hope that will help :)

Comment: I would not suggest using this technique in iOS 11 (and probably since 10.3.1). Because UICollectionView internally malloc's some data in `UICollectionViewData _updateItemCounts` which causes crash (for 100mil. items in one section it generates around 780MB in memory)

Comment: On iOS 12+, its crashing for Int.max as well as Int(INT_MAX) in simulator and device both.

Answer (score 0):

I implement this in [StableCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/aimalygin/StableCollectionViewLayout).

It is based on the UICollectionViewLayout subclass using methods

```
override open func prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates updateItems: [UICollectionViewUpdateItem]) {
super.prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates: updateItems)

// there is possible to calculate a content offset the difference
// with the help layout attributes for each updated item or only visible items
    self.offset = calculate(...)
}

override open func finalizeCollectionViewUpdates() {
    super.finalizeCollectionViewUpdates()
    self.offset = nil
}

override open func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    // there is necessary to add difference to/instead proposedContentOffset
    if let offset = self.offset {
       return offset
    }
    return proposedContentOffset
}
```