# How to scroll to first cell, while swiping the last cell on CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I'm working on a CollectionView with many cells in it. And what I am trying to do is:

- When the user is on the last cell of collectionView, and when the user swipes to see the next cell, I want this collectionView to restarts from the beginning. ( Basically, I need an endless loop )

Hope I could explain it correctly. Waiting for your solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Look here [How to implement horizontally infinite scrolling UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396108/how-to-implement-horizontally-infinite-scrolling-uicollectionview)

Comment: @Ers Tar have you find your answer from my answer?

Comment: @Sagarkoyani yes, thank you so much. it was helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate=self;
        collectionView.dataSource=self;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        if indexpath.row==99{
            self.btnScroll()
           }
        return cell
    }

    func btnScroll() {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.top, animated:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is scrolling to first item, what I need is showing the first item after the last one and continue to scroll like I have more contents in that collectionView

Comment: This is really bad advice, `cellForItemAt` is likely to be also called when prefetching cells, or scrolling back, I doubt in those cases you'll want to automatically scroll to the first item.