# Firing off of subsequent Pagination calls

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, pagination

Okay, I really need your help on this. I am loading a number of elements from firebase lets say 4. These elements are being loaded in a collectionView. Once I reach the bottom of the collection view it should fire off another pagination request or fetch more data however it never does. It always goes to my else statement which lets me know that the pagination did not happen.

Included is my code for my main view controller

```
import UIKit
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator
import SwiftLocation
import CoreLocation
import AMScrollingNavbar

class NewHomeFeedControllerViewController: UIViewController {
    let detailView = EventDetailViewController()
    var allEvents = [Event]()
    let customCellIdentifier1 = "customCellIdentifier1"
    var grideLayout = GridLayout(numberOfColumns: 2)
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    var newHomeFeed: NewHomeFeedControllerViewController?
      let paginationHelper = PaginationHelper<Event>(serviceMethod: PostService.showEvent)
    lazy var dropDownLauncer : DropDownLauncher = {
        let launcer = DropDownLauncher()
        launcer.newHomeFeed = self
        return launcer
    }()

    // 1 IGListKit uses IGListCollectionView, which is a subclass of UICollectionView, which patches some functionality and prevents others.
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        // 2 This starts with a zero-sized rect since the view isn’t created yet. It uses the UICollectionViewFlowLayout just as the ClassicFeedViewController did.
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        // 3 The background color is set to white
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return view
    }()
    func handleDropDownMenu(){
        dropDownLauncer.showDropDown()
    }
    func configureCollectionView() {
        // add pull to refresh
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reloadHomeFeed), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
    func reloadHomeFeed() {
        self.paginationHelper.reloadData(completion: { [unowned self] (events) in
            self.allEvents = events

            if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    func categoryFetch(dropDown: DropDown){
        navigationItem.title = dropDown.name
        paginationHelper.category = dropDown.name
        configureCollectionView()
        reloadHomeFeed()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 0, 0)
        navigationItem.title = "Home"
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = grideLayout
        collectionView.reloadData()
        collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier1)
        //  self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDropDownMenu))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        configureCollectionView()
        reloadHomeFeed()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let navigationController = self.navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
            navigationController.followScrollView(self.collectionView, delay: 50.0)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        if let navigationController = navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
            navigationController.stopFollowingScrollView()
        }
    }

     func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
        if let navigationController = navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
            navigationController.showNavbar(animated: true)
        }
        return true
    }
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        grideLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

extension NewHomeFeedControllerViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //let selectedEvent = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
        //let eventDetailVC
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
            //  print("Look here for event name")
            // print(detailView.eventName)
            detailView.eventKey = allEvents[indexPath.row].key!
            detailView.eventPromo = allEvents[indexPath.row].currentEventPromo!
            detailView.currentEvent = allEvents[indexPath.row]
            present(detailView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)

        }
        print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }
}

extension NewHomeFeedControllerViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allEvents.count
    }
    // The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier1, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let imageURL = URL(string: allEvents[indexPath.item].currentEventImage)
        print(imageURL ?? "")
        customCell.sampleImage.af_setImage(withURL: imageURL!)
        return customCell
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: CustomCell, forItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section >= allEvents.count - 1 {
            // print("paginating for post")
            paginationHelper.paginate(completion: { [unowned self] (events) in
                self.allEvents.append(contentsOf: events)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }else{
            print("Not paginating")
        }
    }

}


extension NewHomeFeedControllerViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.item == 0 || indexPath.item == 1 {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: grideLayout.itemSize.height)
        }else{
            return grideLayout.itemSize
        }
    }
}
```

My Pagination is accomplished through this helper method

```
protocol Keyed {
    var key: String? { get set }
}

// Create a new instance using a genetic type
//let paginationHelper = MGPaginationHelper<Post>()

// Generic class type



//   1. initial - no data has been loaded yet
//   2.  ready - ready and waiting for next request to paginate and load the next page
//   3.  loading - currently paginating and waiting for data from Firebase
//   4.  end - all data has been paginated

enum PaginationState
{
    case initial
    case ready
    case loading
    case end
}

class PaginationHelper<T : Keyed>
{
    // MARK: - Properties

    // 1. page size - Determines the number of posts that will be on each page
    // 2. serviceMethod - The service method that will return paginated data
    // 3. state - The current pagination state of the helper
    // 4. lastobjectKey - Firebase uses object keys to determine the last position of the page. We'lll need to use this as an offset for paginating.
    let pageSize: UInt
    let serviceMethod: (UInt, String?,String?, @escaping (([T]) -> Void)) -> Void
    var state: PaginationState = .initial
    var lastObjectKey: String?
    var category: String?

    // MARK: - Init
    //    Can change the default page size for our helper
    //    Set the service method that will be paginated and return data
    init(pageSize: UInt = 4, serviceMethod: @escaping (UInt, String?,String?, @escaping (([T]) -> Void)) -> Void) {
        self.pageSize = pageSize
        self.serviceMethod = serviceMethod
    }


    // 1 Notice our completion parameter type. We use our generic type to enforce that we return type T.
    func paginate(completion: @escaping([T]) -> Void)
    {
        // 2 We switch on our helper's state to determine the behavior of our helper when paginate(completion:) is called
        switch state
        {
        // 3 For our initial state, we make sure that the lastObjectKey is nil use the fallthrough keyword to execute the ready case below.
        case .initial:
            lastObjectKey = nil
            fallthrough
        //4 For our ready state, we make sure to change the state to loading and execute our service method to return the paginated data.
        case .ready:
            state = .loading
          //  print(lastObjectKey)
            serviceMethod(pageSize, lastObjectKey, category) { [unowned self] (objects: [T]) in
                //5 We use the defer keyword to make sure the following code is executed whenever the closure returns. This is helpful for removing duplicate code.
                defer {
                    //6 If the returned last returned object has a key value, we store that in lastObjectKey to use as a future offset for paginating. Right now the compiler will throw an error because it cannot infer that T has a property of key. We'll fix that next.
                    if let lastObjectKey = objects.last?.key {
                        self.lastObjectKey = lastObjectKey
                      //  print(self.lastObjectKey)
                      //  print(lastObjectKey)
                    }
                    // 7 We determine if we've paginated through all content because if the number of objects returned is less than the page size, we know that we're only the last page of objects.
                    self.state = objects.count < Int(self.pageSize) ? .end : .ready
                }

                // 8 If lastObjectKey of the helper doesn't exist, we know that it's the first page of data so we return the data as is.
                guard let _ = self.lastObjectKey else {
                   // print(self.lastObjectKey)
                    return completion(objects)
                }

                // 9 Due to implementation details of Firebase, whenever we page with the lastObjectKey, the previous object from the last page is returned. Here we need to drop the first object which will be a duplicate post in our timeline. This happens whenever we're no longer on the first page.
              //  print(objects.last?.key)
              //  let newObjects = Array(objects.dropLast())
              //  print(newObjects)
                print("\n")
              //  print(objects)
                print("\n")
                completion(objects)

            }

        //10 If the helper is currently paginating or has no more content, the helper returns and doesn't do anything.
        case . loading, .end:
            return
        }
    }

    //  resets the pagination helper to it's initial state
    func reloadData(completion: @escaping ([T]) -> Void)
    {
        state = .initial
        paginate(completion: completion)
    }


}
```

Which calls this function

```
import Foundation
import  UIKit
import Firebase

struct PostService {
    static func create(for event: String?,for vidURL: String) {
        // 1
        guard let key = event else {
            return 
        }
        let storyUrl = vidURL
        // 2
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{
            return
        }
        let story = Story(url: storyUrl)
        let dict = story.dictValue
       let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("Stories").child(key).childByAutoId()
        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("Stories").child(key).childByAutoId()
        postRef.updateChildValues(dict)
        userRef.updateChildValues(dict)
    }
    static func showEvent(pageSize: UInt, lastPostKey: String? = nil, category: String? = nil,completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> Void) {
        //getting firebase root directory
       // print(lastPostKey)
      //  print("came here")
        var currentEvents = [Event]()
        let eventsByLocationRef = Database.database().reference().child("eventsbylocation").child(User.current.location!)
        //let ref = Database.database().reference().child("events")
        var query = eventsByLocationRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toFirst: pageSize)
        if let lastPostKey = lastPostKey {
          //  print(lastPostKey)
            query = query.queryEnding(atValue: lastPostKey)
        }
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
         //   print(snapshot)
           // print(snapshot.value)
            guard let allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else{
                return
            }
            allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in
            // print(snapshot.value ?? "")
                print(category)
                EventService.show(forEventKey: snapshot.value as! String,eventCategory: category, completion: { (event) in
                    currentEvents.append(event!)
                   // print("\n\n\n\n\n\n")
                   // print("Finished an event")
                   // print(currentEvents.count)
                    completion(currentEvents)
                })

            })


        })

    }



}
```

The previous code uses this function to ultimately pull the data from firebase by the key

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth


struct EventService {

    static func show(forEventKey eventKey: String, eventCategory: String? = nil, completion: @escaping (Event?) -> Void) {
       // print(eventKey)
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("events").child(eventKey)
       // print(eventKey)
                //pull everything
                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith: { (snapshot,eventKey) in
                    print(snapshot.value ?? "")
                    guard let event = Event(snapshot: snapshot) else {
                        return completion(nil)
                    }
                    if event.category == eventCategory{
                        completion(event)
                    }
                    if eventCategory == nil || eventCategory == "" || eventCategory == "Home" {
                        completion(event)
                    }
                })




    }
}
```

The only reason I included all these methods is for a better tracing of what is going on. I have looked at these functions up and down and I can't seem t figure out what is going wrog. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wow - that's a LOT of code for us to look through. Can you reduce it down to something a bit more manageable? Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added al this for trcing@Jay

Comment: if I leave something out then I may get asked to describe one of these methods in detail@Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of code in the question, so I may not be on the right track, but I do want to help and I have a theory. Right now you're checking to see if you're on the last item in the `collectionView` like this:

`if indexPath.section >= allEvents.count - 1`

If you print `indexPath.section`, I bet it will always be the same. Probably always 0 because your `collectionView` only has one section. Instead try:

`if indexPath.item >= allEvents.count - 1`

That should return the number of the item instead of the section the item is in.

Like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: CustomCell, forItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item >= allEvents.count - 1 {
        // print("paginating for post")
        paginationHelper.paginate(completion: { [unowned self] (events) in
            self.allEvents.append(contentsOf: events)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    } else {
        print("Not paginating")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi when I tried that it still did not work for some reason

Comment: when you print `indexPath.item` and `allEvents.count-`1, what results do you get?

Comment: Indexpath.item is 0

Comment: allEvents.count = 3

Comment: How many UICollectionViewCells are showing on the screen at any one time? Are cells all vertical like a tableView? That function is definitely where the issue is, but you may want to look into using the UIScrollViewDelegate instead since UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246394/showing-cells-in-demands-in-uicollectionview-with-vertical-infinite-scroll

Comment: okay that seems to be working but now I have another small issue